# EF Core With Where Condition to Filter Decimal Data Type With LIKE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a database column with the following decimal data type with precision in the database. I want to perform a query with filter that number include thousand separator using Entity Framework Core with Contains or EF Like function. Usually the syntax I use on SQL server is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(MONEY, Rate), 3) LIKE '%12,%'
```

I tried to convert the numeric data to string type but got an error.

```cs
.Where(x => x.Rate.ToString("N2").Contains($"{searchValue}))
```

And I've been browsing but haven't found it yet. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks.

**Update:**

The error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

```
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 count)
at Game.BackEnd.Controllers.AdaDeyController.GetData(DataTableRequestModel post) in C:\MyGame\Game.BackEnd\Controllers\AdaDeyController.cs:line 261
at lambda_method216(Closure, Object)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, bjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**Update**
LinQ Code

```cs
var query = _context.AdaDey
    .Include(x => x.SourceSatu)
    .Include(y => y.TargetSatu)
    .Select(s => new AdaDey()
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Date = s.StartDate,
        Rate = s.Rate,
        SourceSatu = new SourceSatu()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Code = s.SourceSatu!.Code,
            Name = s.SourceSatu.Name
        },
        TargetSatu = new TargetSatu()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Code = s.TargetSatu!.Code,
            Name = s.TargetSatu.Name
        }
    })
    .Where(x => (x.Rate).ToString("N2").Contains($"{searchValue}"));
```

**UPDATE** AdaDeyControllers.cs Line:261

```
return Json(new
                {
                    draw = post.draw,
                    recordsFiltered = dataResponse?.DataResponse?.Count ?? 0,
                    recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                    data = dataResponse?.DataResponse.Skip(skip).Take(post.length)
                }, opt);
```

Comment: What error has occurred?

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source').

Comment: @Amigo use edit to update your question with that information: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76834047/edit. Also please provide a full stack Trace instead of such a generic message.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Ok, I've updated

Comment: The stack trace indicates that it's not an Entity Framework issue because the code is being executed in memory using the linq2objects. Are you calling  `something.Skip(...)` anywhere in that GetData controller method? Because the stack Trace indicates that skip is being called on a sequence that is `null`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: I don't use the .Skip syntax. I also include the LinQ code that I use.

Comment: Don't think that EF Core can translate `.ToString("N2")`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that might be the case, but if you look at the stack trace the error is thrown by `System.Linq.Enumerable` but, the code he just included is at odds with the stack Trace

Comment: @Amigo, which EF Core version do you use?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yes, shown query is not related to exception.

Comment: I'm becoming increasingly confused. Why are you converting a decimal type into a double type and then using formatting on it? Also, why are you using string interpolation when the string you're searching for is contained in a single value.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I'm using EF Core version 7.0.5. I converted the Decimal data type to Double just for testing, and I didn't realize that what I pasted was the code that I converted to double.

Comment: What is at `AdaDeyController.cs:line 261`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, What is in AcaDemy Controller.cs:line 261 is the return syntax. Because there is an error above so that the syntax return becomes an error too.

Comment: In this line you have `Skip`, which I do not see in sample.

Comment: So,  `dataResponse?.DataResponse` is null and you have your exception.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Nobody seems to wonder why you even do this. What's the use of a query that returns e.g. `12,000`, as well as `912,000` or `999,999,912,000`? I suspect something should be solved on a higher level (AKA "XY-problem").

Comment: @GertArnoldisonstrike, I want the user to input data that will be searched according to what the user sees (WYSIWYG).

Comment: IMO a lot of effort for a useless feature. That's not how users want to filter numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [like method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-7.0) for this

For your example it would look something like this:

```
.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like((string)(object)x.Rate, $"%{searchValue}%")
```

Comment: I've tried it with the function before, and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm using it exaclty like this in one of our applications to filter on an int value.